# Scala: How can I replace lazy and save my functionality?

Tags: scala

I have a simple code:

```
def task(t: => Int): Unit = t

lazy val tsk = {
  println(2)
  throw new RuntimeException
}

task {
  {
    println(1) // additional job
    tsk
  }
}
```

If I make my `val` not lazy, It will be printed `2` and `stacktrace`. To keep additional job I need to make my val lazy. I want to avoid it. Is there any  possibility to use just val and print `2`, `1` and `stacktrace`?

PS

I can replace it with `def` and get behavior what I need.

```
def tsk = {...}
```

But I want to use `val` here.

Comment: Are you willing to modifying the *invocation* of `tsk`?  E. g. would `println(1); tsk()` be acceptable or does that need to not change as well?

Comment: No, I want something different. `tsk()` is the same as `def tsk`. So I want to find a diff approach.

Comment: Currently turning `lazy val` into `def` would not change functionality. What exactly should `tsk` do? `lazy val` is technically closer do `def` than it is to `val`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "just `val`" with this initializer, the initializer will run and throw an exception: that's what `val` *means*.

You could change the type of `tsk` to `() => Int`:

```
def task(t: => Int): Unit = t

val tsk = () => {
  println(2)
  throw new RuntimeException
}

task {
  {
    println(1) // additional job
    tsk()
  }
}
```

Or hide it in an `object`, which are initialized lazily:

```
def task(t: => Int): Unit = t

object Tsk {
  val x = {
    println(2)
    throw new RuntimeException
  }
}

import Tsk._

task {
  {
    println(1) // additional job
    x
  }
}
```

Comment: Just be careful, because with `() => { ... }` you lose caching of the result. Function is evaluated every time when it is called. Lazy val is evaluated the first time it is needed and result is reused later on.

Comment: @Nebril Not in this case: [if the initialization of a lazy val throws an exception, it will attempt to reinitialize the val at next access](https://twitter.com/viktorklang/status/104483846002704384)